How to increase recursive invocations limit in AWS lambda?
I have a lambda function that asynchronously invokes itself in a chain reaction 30 times in  a row, however AWS stops at invocation #16 because of the infinite loop detection
Is there a way I can raise that limit of 16 for my function?

You'll need to contact support to disable recursion detection.  (And probably explain that you're aware of the cost implications if you have an out of control Lambda)

Outright disabling the limit is too risky for my taste... If increasing the threshold is not an option, do you know any potential workarounds?

This is me being a little noob. However, have you thought about using SQS for it? If order is important, you can configure it to be a FIFO, else you could just use it to parallelize the process. You could add a property or define the event in a way that it doesn't infinitely trigger other 30x invocations. Your lambda will then get triggered by the original event or the new SQS.

I've never used SQS before, however the documentation says infinite loop detection works with SQS queues as well

Can you tell us more about your use-case for requiring recursion? Are you just trying to run one big job while avoiding the 15-minute limit, or is it actually processing 30 different 'things'?

It is doing one big job avoiding the 15 minute. I am already parallelizing as much as possible... I reality I am running 4 lambdas each one with a 30 element chain reaction

Square peg in a round hole. Consider using ECS Fargate.

You can allow for recursiveness, while this is dangerous and requires failover mechanisms, can be done.
aws lambda put-function-recursion-config --function-name yourFunctionName --recursive-loop Allow

As per other solutions, using a FIFO queue will increase the complexity with no real benefits, since AWS recursiveness protection also detects when it happens in said scenario:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-recursion.html
